# base64 or hex encoded Int8 binary string to Int32Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I have a binary string that must travel over a ws websocket (I can't use websocket.io) and so is being JSON.stringified. e.g. `var msg.data = data.toString('base64')`

On the other end, I want that data back not as byte wide binary, but as an array of 32 bit integers. e.g. if the binary data is [0, 0, 0, 1] going in, I want [1] coming out. Each output element is 4 bytes.

If I just take the binary string directly, I can `new Int32Array(data)` and I'm golden; the result is 1/4 the length of the original and each 32 bit element is made up from 4 of the original byte wide elements.

But when I've encoded it, then decoded with `var data = Buffer.from(msg.data, 'base64')` then `new Int32Array(data)`is the same length as the original, and each 32 byte element is made from ONE of the original 8 byte elements. `Int32Array.from(data)` does the same.

I'm not finding any answer by searching, everyone appears to be ok with byte wide data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.buffer

I was forgetting .buffer.

`new Int32Array(data.buffer)` works perfectly.